# pass value from drop down menu to textarea with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Using Jquery or javascript. What is the best way to send the value of an option from a drop down menu to the textarea listed below. So if the user selects one of the names in the drop down it will sends its value to the textarea field. the select menu is in its own iframe (iframe name is boxmain) and the text area is in its own iframe (iframe name is boxform).

```
<select id="usernames" name="usernames">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="name001">JeffCool</option>
    <option value="name002">IAMsam</option>
</select>

<textarea name="name" cols="15" rows="1" class="class"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler on your `<select>`, the simplest form of this:

```
 $("#usernames").change(function() {
   $("textarea[name=pst]").val($(this).val());
 });
```

What this does is what the `<select>` changes value, it takes the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (the `value` of the `<option>` just chosen) and *sets* that value on the `<textarea>` using the same method.

Comment: @Nick Craver♦ Thanks! i actually have the drop down menu in one iframe and the textarea in another iframe is it possible to send the value across iframes?

Comment: the drop down iframe name is name="boxmain" and textarea iframe name is name="boxform"

Comment: @jennifer - Are the frames on the same domain? There are security restrictions in place if not.

Comment: @Nick Craver♦ yes they are on the same domain

Comment: @jennifer - you'd put this code in the `<select>`'s frame (after the `<select>` or in a `document.ready` handler, either or).  Then, change the inside selector to be: `$("textarea[name=pst]", parent.frames['boxform'].document)`, rather than just `$("textarea[name=pst]")`

Comment: @jennifer - you're not including jQuery on that page (see your console for errors), be sure to both do that, and wrap the above code in `$(function() { CODEHERE });` if placing the `<script>` block before the `<select>` element in the HTML.